# how many services can be invoked from an activity in android programming?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-service

I am working on a project where there is a case when Activity A passes some data to Service A and some data to Service B. And I am not able to figure out how

Comment: Please using Thread. :D

Comment: The services guide http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html may help.